# it is a systematic approach "to obtain" or "obtaining"?

Tags: word-usage, gerunds, to-infinitive

Would you please explain the use of *to infinitive* and to, as a preposition, + gerund, and when do we use one over the other? Many times, I have a problem deciding whether to use a regular *to infinitive* or treat the "to" as a preposition and add an `-ing` to the verb to make it gerund.  I've gathered some sentences using `to + gerund` below:

> 1. It is an **approach to obtaining**.....
> 2. It is a **key to making**.....

Other than "key/approach/committed/dedicated `to +ing`," could you guys think of other words?

Comment: Could you share the complete sentences?

Comment: It is a systematic approach to implementing our hiring process. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it might be simpler if you thought of your choice as "to + infinitive" and "for + gerund"? Don't get too caught up in only using "to".

Comment: In your examples, both nouns _key_ and _approach_ collocates with a preposition after them. If you need to use a form of verb after a _preposition_, it's definitely a _gerund_. _Key to sth_, _approach to sth_. That aside, take a look at this link since where to use gdrund and infinitive is a long story. http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm

Answer (score 1):

Mainly, if *to* is a preposition, we need to use a noun after it. It means if we a verb after that, then we should use the gerund form.

Now we need to know how to recognize if a *to* is a preposition.

> 1. When *to* is part of a [phrasal verb](http://www.learn-english-today.com/phrasal-verbs/phrasal-verb-list.htm) then it's a pereposition.
>
> [I’m really looking forward to seeing him.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-american-english/look-forward-to-something?q=look+forward+to)
>
> 2. When *to* is used after an adjective:
>
> [The Boy Scouts organization is dedicated to helping boys become moral and productive adults.](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dedicated)
>
> 3. In a noun + preposition construction:
>
> [It is an approach to obtaining....](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73534/33000)
>
> [It is a key to making.....](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/73534/33000)